# Is it possible in magento 2.1.8 to create categories from product name like in shopify smart collections?

Tags: shopify, magento2.1

Is it possible in magento 2.1.8 to create smart categories like shopify smart collections?

We want categories like shopify smart collections. i.e if any product name contain 'xyz' then category named 'xyz' created automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to create smart collection in magento. For that you have to first override product save action and then in that action you have to add functionality during creating/saving product
1) if category exist with same as product's name then gets its id and add that id to product
2) if category not exist then create id with that name and add its id to product.

In this way you can create smart collections

Thanks